# iPad/iOS full tutorial for seniors in Chinese?

Tags: ios, ipad, language

I cant seem to find any tutorials in Chinese which teach older Chinese elders how to use iOS or an iPad. My parents are not very good at English and I can only find English tutorials online. They barely know how to use iOS or iPad controls even after owning an iPhone for two years.
Even if I just change the language of the iPad itself to Chinese, it won’t help them learn how to use “advanced” technology, I’ve tried.

Does anybody know where I could find a full comprehensive tutorial starting from the very basics to more advanced stuff, all in Chinese? It’s extremely frustrating to not see any useful tutorials at all in other languages.

Any useful help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The official iPad user guide is available in lots of languages:

https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/welcome/ipados/localeselector

For example, zh-cn:

https://support.apple.com/zh-cn/guide/ipad/welcome/ipados